# Can the Nest API be used to trigger a Rush Hour Rewards event?

Tags: nest-api

Since my energy company (OG&E) is not currently partnered with Nest for Rush Hour Rewards I don't get to take advantage of the savings offered by the program. However, my energy company does send me an email to let me know what tomorrow's peak time rate will be. I would like to setup a tool to parse this email and notify my Nest so that it will trigger a Rush Hour Rewards event. Is this possible with the current Nest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research it looks like this type of application is prohibited by the [Terms of Service for the Nest API](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/tos):

> III. Prohibitions When using the Nest API and other Nest Developer
>   Materials, unless otherwise approved in writing by Nest, you will not:
>
> ...
>
> `4.` Create a Client that performs demand response or other energy management programs such as those offered by electric, gas, water or
>   similar companies or energy markets.
>
> ...

Not sure what the purpose of that restriction is or if it really applies to my situation since I only want to use if personal purposes not make it available for others. Oh well, I guess I'll just have to wait for OG&E to partner with Nest in order for me to save money and energy. :(

Comment: The restriction is surely to avoid conflicting with deals they've made with energy providers.

For personal use I can't see how they would care, or even notice what you were doing.